# Create a file only if the directory exists?

Tags: linux, redhat, unix, puppet

I am trying to write the module where it creates the file if directory exists or else it shouldn't do anything.

```
class puppetmodule{
  exec { 'chk_dir_exists':
    command => 'test -d /usr/dir1',
    path    =>  ["/usr/bin","/usr/sbin", "/bin"],
  } ->

  file {'usr/dir1/test.txt':
    ensure => 'file',
    owner  => 'root',
    group  => 'root',
    mode   => '0750',
  }
}
```

Below is the error it is throwing. Please advice me on this.

> Error: test -d /usr/dir1 returned 1 instead of one of [0]

Comment: Why not create the directory and then create the file, instead of checking if it exists first?

Comment: This directory is not present in all the servers.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this will work:

```
  $dir = "/usr/dir1"

  exec { "chk_${dir}_exist":
    command => "true",
    path    =>  ["/usr/bin","/usr/sbin", "/bin"],
    onlyif  => "test -d ${dir}"
  }

  file {"${dir}/test.txt":
    ensure => file,
    owner  => 'root',
    group  => 'root',
    mode   => '0750',
    require => Exec["chk_${dir}_exist"],
  }
```

**Explanation:**

`onlyif  => "test -d ${dir}"`

means that the Exec resource is only created if the output of `test -d` is true.

`require => Exec["chk_${dir}_exist"]`

means the File resource is created only if the Exec resource exists.

If the directory does not exist, the puppet run will generate an error indicating that it cannot create File resource because the Exec resource does not exist. This is expected and can be safely ignored as the rest of the puppet catalog still gets applied.

If the directory exists, the File resource is created and applied.

Comment: This does not work for me using puppet 3.8

Comment: The require attribute is no longer present.

Answer (score 1):

Puppet is about end state. You can ensure a file exists with the state you specify or is absent. If you need to do some branching (**if**) logic, Puppet supports that as well. See conditionals in the documentation - https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_conditional.html

```
$directory_exists = <insert logic here> 
   
if $directory_exists {
  file {'usr/dir1/test.txt':
    ensure => 'file',
    owner  => 'root',
    group  => 'root',
    mode   => '0750',
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello ferventcoder, Thanks for your response. Please correct me if I am wrong. I tried below code and it Doesn't throw any errors but it doesn't create the file even if directory present.      $directory_exists = "(test -d /usr/dir1)" if $directory_exists =='true'{ file {'usr/dir1/test.txt': ensure => 'file', owner => 'root', group => 'root', mode => '0750', } }

Comment: I think you should use a `notify` resource to tell you what the value of `$directory_exists` comes back as. You could be running into possible permissions issues.

Comment: The link is broken, I believe this is the new one: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_conditional.html